# GSM Sim300 response not Receive in atmega16

Tags: arduino

Am working on Sim300, trying to receive sms on atmega16  via serial communication.
When i send " *23# " sms to gsm modem from my mobile, gsm sends
" \r\n+CMGR:\s"REC\sUNREAD","+919762148043",,"14/03/13,23:04:32+22"\r\n*23#\r\n\r\nOK\r\n "
as response on serial port.
Am getting this data on atmega16, but only 
" \r\n+CMGR:\s"REC\sUNREAD","+919762148043",,"14/03/13,23:04:32+22"\r "
this much of string where that " *23#" is my actual sms and am interested in "23".
my firmware looks like this,

```
while(Serial.available())
  {
    char tempChar = Serial.read();
    if(tempChar == '+')
    {
      isPreSms = true;
      lcd.print('+');
    }
    else if((tempChar == '\r') && (isPreSms == true))
    {
      isPreSms = false;
      lcd.print('r');
    }
    else if(tempChar == '*')
    {
      digitalWrite(OKLed, HIGH);
      isSms = true;
      lcd.print('*');
    }
    else if((tempChar == '#') && (isSms == true))
    {
      digitalWrite(powerLed, HIGH);
      isSms = false;
      lcd.print(sms);
    }
    else if(isSms)
    {
      digitalWrite(alertLed, HIGH);
      sms += tempChar;
    }
  }
  lcd.print('@');
}
```

Am expecting "+++r*23@" as output on lcd. I have checked, it receives '+' as well as '\r' but not '*' and further. Am stuck here, please help, what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i solved it.
There is problem with size of serial buffer. I increased it's size to 128 bytes and its working fine now.